# pyspark is not running - mac

Tags: macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run pyspark on my local machine and somehow I can not. I have downloaded the latest version of the Spark and set the following path in .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Users/user/Downloads/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin:$PATH"
```

When I run this command:

```
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook” pyspark
```

Nothing happens. I have done everything based on instructions and what I see as the output of that command is this symbol followed by nothing:

```
>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks